# I made a basic quiz app using flutter and in the result screen where the correct answers and user answers are displayed but the color and font isn't

Tags: android, flutter, dart, screen, development-environment

I made a basic quiz app using flutter and in the result screen where the correct answers and user answers are displayed but the colour and font isn't displayed as expected it's like the code for styling the answers isn't working.

Here I'm providing the full code and can someone tell me that why isn't this working.

```
import 'package:adv_basics/question_identifier.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class SummaryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const SummaryItem(this.itemData, {super.key});

  final Map<String, Object> itemData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isCorrectAnswer =
        itemData['user_answer'] == itemData['correct_answer'];

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 8,
      ),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          QuestionIdentifier(
            isCorrectAnswer: isCorrectAnswer,
            questionIndex: itemData['question'] as int,
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  itemData['question'] as String,
                  style: GoogleFont.lato(
                    color: Color.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  itemData['user_answer'] as String,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 202, 171, 252),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  itemData['correct_answer'] as String,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 181, 254, 246),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[the final result screen for the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80mLa.png)

Comment: You are missing two "s" only.  `GoogleFonts` and `Colors`. 
Like this:

`Text(
                  itemData['question'] as String,
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),`

Answer (score 0):

the issues is here :

your code :

```
GoogleFont.lato(
                    color: Color.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               ),
```

the correction :

```
GoogleFonts.lato(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
```

you just need to add the "s" to the `GoogleFonts.lato` and `Colors`.